# how to call the jQuery code for the contents which are pulled through the ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This might be very foolish question but I'm really stucked with this. So, I'm pulling the contents in my html file from the external php file using jquery ajax.

html:

```
+-------------------+
| some contents 1   | this would be changed with click button using ajax
+-------------------+
|   click button    |
+-------------------+
```

php:

```
+-------------------+
| some contents 1   |
+-------------------+
| some contents 2   |
+-------------------+
| some contents 3   |
+-------------------+
```

When I use jquery for the contents it works with html `some contents 1` but not to the pulled contents i.e. for 2,3 do not work. Please note: this time I'm not using my jquery code inside the ajax code but using external js file.

Like:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  console.log('test');//doesn't log.
});
```

But surprised:

```
$('body').click(function(){
  console.log('test');//only body element clicked logs.
});
```

So, how to call the jQuery code for the contents which are pulled through the ajax. Note: I've used the code in the ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the content is generated after the DOM load.

Do like this:

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
  console.log('test');
});
```

**Note:** instead of document you can use the container element id in which content in loaded

Comment: oh! god, I'm so foolish. I din't think about that... but how with second code in my question work....

Comment: and note instead of document you can use the container element id in which content in loaded

Comment: with the second code inside the function the elements are also pulled from ajax... even though they are not event delegation...but works...

Comment: @C-link Its because of `body` was available when page was ready.

Comment: but inside the body I've called suppose $('img').show(); ... this works... even the img is from ajax call....

Comment: in the second one you have written body click event and its loaded when page loaded so that's why it works

Comment: because you can manipulate element that dynamically loaded after page load but if you want to write any event on it for example, click,hover etc you need to use delegated event